# Html and javascript code Concatenation problem

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append HTML syntax with javascript and onClick trying to pass a function with 2 parameters. But while passing the parameters I am doing something wrong in concatenation. Please help.Here is the append code.

```
addPanelHtml += "<li><a href='#' id='btnhistory" + i+ "' onclick='histDrpDwnEdt("+chkval+"','" + i+ ")'>History Parameters</a></li>";
```

while running the program I am getting error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**

Comment: Try, ``addPanelHtml += "<li><a href='#' id='btnhistory" + i + "'" + " onclick='histDrpDwnEdt("+chkval+"','" + i+ ")'>History Parameters</a></li>";``

Comment: what is your `addPanelHtml` ? Can you provide more of your code please?

Comment: I think your error is here: `onclick='histDrpDwnEdt("+chkval+"','" + i+ ")` you should remove the single quote signs around the comma (if both `chhval` and `i` are numeric values): `onclick='histDrpDwnEdt("+chkval+"," + i+ ")` or you should add one before `chval` and one afer `i` (if they are string values):  `onclick='histDrpDwnEdt('"+chkval+"','" + i+ "')`.

Comment: ... actually, if `chhval` and `i` are string values, you should add the single quote signs *and escape them*: `onclick='histDrpDwnEdt(\'"+chkval+"\',\'" +i+ "\')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend to use template strings in this use case

Here the solution with template strings

```
addPanelHtml += `<li><a href='#' id='btnhistory${i}' onclick='histDrpDwnEdt(${chkval}, ${i})'>History Parameters</a></li>`;
```

Then you can get rid of all these `+ " " +` concatenations and just use `${}` to enclose your variables.

This improves the readabilty of your code by far.

Here you can read more about template strings

- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: The suggestion is good but the string you provided is not correct; it should be ``addPanelHtml += `<li><a href='#' id='btnhistory${i}' onclick='histDrpDwnEdt(${chkval}, ${i})'>History Parameters</a></li>`;``

Comment: @developerExecutive, actually that is called a template literal or a template string (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), as correctly mentioned by Alex, while concat is a method of `String.prototype` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) and it has not changed in ES6. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try instead of writting the ***'***, try like this ***\'***:

```
addPanelHtml += "<li><a href=\'#\' id=\'btnhistory" + i+ "\' onclick=\'histDrpDwnEdt("+chkval+"\',\'" + i+ ")\'>History Parameters</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```js
var addPanelHtml = '', i = 0, chkval = 1;

addPanelHtml += '<li><a href="#" id="btnhistory' + i + '" onclick="histDrpDwnEdt(' + chkval + ', ' + i + ')">History Parameters</a></li>';

console.log(addPanelHtml);
```