# Javascript discount for price classes

Tags: javascript

Ive been trying to add a discount to price classes for a couple of days now but haven’t been able to. The current js code I have is a simple addition calculator, but I want it to discount prices between 100 and 500 with 10% and prices over 500 get 20% discount. I also want it to show the price before and after the discount if possible.

The code I have for the calculator so far, its working fine:

```js
function calculate() {
  var field1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var field2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

  var result = parseFloat(field1) + parseFloat(field2);


  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Totalpris är " + result;
  }

}
```

```html
Artikel 1 <input type="text2" id="num1">
<br>
<br> Artikel 2 <input type="text2" id="num2">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="calculate()">Totalpris</button>

<h1 id="answer"></h1>
```

[image]

Comment: do in the input field type=number

Answer (score 0):

You should give **type** **number**

text2 is not a valid value for the **type attribute**
Instead of this

```
Artikel 1 <input type="text2" id="num1">
<br>
<br>
Artikel 2 <input type="text2" id="num2">
```

Do this

```
<input type ="number" id="num1">
<input type="number" id="num2">
```

Here is the solution for your challenge

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        a.htmlArtikel 1 <input id="num1" type="number">
<br>
<br>
Artikel 2 <input type="number" id="num2">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="calculate()">Totalpris</button>
<script>
    function calculate(){
    let result = ``;
    const field1 =   document.getElementById("num1").value;
    const field2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

    let amount_before_discount = parseFloat(field1)+parseFloat(field2);
    let amount_after_discount = amount_before_discount

    if(amount_after_discount >= 100 && amount_before_discount < 500){
        amount_after_discount = amount_before_discount * 0.9;
    // for the second question, look at the comments     
    result += `After an discount of 10% the new price is 
    ${amount_after_discount}`
        
    }else if(amount_before_discount >= 500){
        amount_after_discount = amount_before_discount * 0.8;
        result += `After an discount of 20% the new price is 
       ${amount_after_discount}`
    }

    if (!isNaN(amount_before_discount)) {
            // here you can innerHtml then the result

    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = 
       "Totalpris är "+amount_after_discount+". Was "+amount_before_discount;
  }
    

    }
</script>

<h1 id="answer"></h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code, i'm just wondering if there's also a way of showing how much the discount percentage (%) is for the different price classes. Example: when it's 10% discount then it says "after 10% discount the new price is" or after 20% it says "after 20% discount the new price is" I posted a picture in my first question but it's in a different language, I think you will understand my point anyways

Comment: Sure just build an string in the 
let result = `${amount_after_discount} after a discount of x %`
x is either 10 or 20 depends on in which condition you are

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65231409/html-and-javascript-code-concatenation-problem/65231506#65231506 here I had an answer with the template string syntax, you can check this out

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple to do with some if statements.

```js
function calculate() {
  var field1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var field2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

  var beforeDiscount = parseFloat(field1) + parseFloat(field2);
  var afterDiscount = beforeDiscount;

  if (beforeDiscount >= 100 && beforeDiscount < 500) {
      afterDiscount = beforeDiscount * 0.9;
  } else if (beforeDiscount >= 500) {
      afterDiscount = beforeDiscount * 0.8;
  }

  if (!isNaN(beforeDiscount)) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = 
       "Totalpris är "+afterDiscount+". Was "+beforeDiscount;
  }
}
```

```html
Artikel 1 <input type="text2" id="num1">
<br>
<br>
Artikel 2 <input type="text2" id="num2">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="calculate()">Totalpris</button>

<h1 id="answer"></h1>
```

Comment: You have a code error in your snippet: `result is not defined`.

Comment: You use result from the original example

Comment: Oops. Fixed that now

Comment: Thank you so much for the code, i'm just wondering if there's also a way of showing how much the discount percentage (%) is for the different price classes. Example: when it's 10% discount then it says "after 10% discount the new price is" or after 20% it says "after 20% discount the new price is" I posted a picture in my first question but it's in a different language, I think you will understand my point anyways